# TinyMCE Image Editor Integration

Tags: tinymce

I have written Image Editor in java which I want to integrate with TinyMCE.Although I am so confused.I have a custom toolbar button and I open my ImageEditor onclick as below.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file : "/ImageEditor/index.jsp",
    title : 'Image Manager',
    width : 800,  // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
    height : 600,
    resizable : "yes",
    inline : "yes", 
    close_previous : "no"
});
```

This opens my editor but now what code I need to write on "Set Image" button of that popup so that I can insert selected image to TinyMCE editor ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following code in side the opened pop up .

var ed = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('elm1');
var code = GetSelectedImage();
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, code);